# d3.js I want to change the data value to a percentage

Tags: d3.js

I want to use the data value from json file and use it in d3.js.
I would like to display the data in the json file by using a bar graph in 0 to 100% on the x axis, and convert it to a percentage and graph it.
I do not know how to change the data value to a percentage.
So there is no longer any progress in the code.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>D3_percent_Bar</title>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<svg id="bar1" width="250" height="250"></svg>

<script>

var margin={top:10,bottom:10,left:15,right:15},
 w = 250 - margin.left - margin.right,
 h = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var canvas = d3.select("#bar1")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",w+margin.left+margin.right)
  .attr("height",h+margin.top+margin.bottom);


var formatter = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
 .range([0,w]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
 .scale(x)
 .ticks(10,formatter);


 
var data = d3.json("data_F.json", function (error,data){

 alert(data);
 alert(error);

 var max = Math.max.apply(Math, data);
 var percents = (data / max)*100;
 
 
 //var maxX = d3.max(data, function(d){return d.num2;});
 //var minX = d3.min(data, function(d){return d.num1;});
 
 //x.domain([0,maxX]);
 
 canvas.append("g")
 .attr("class","axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+","+50+")")
 .call(xAxis);
 
 
 
 var bar = canvas.selectAll("rect")
   .data(data)
   .attr("class","bar")
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x",margin.left+40)
   .attr("width", function(d){return d.num1;})
   .attr("y",function(d,i){return i*50;})
   .attr("height",40);
   //.attr("height",barHeight-1)
 
 //.attr("transform","translate(0,4)");
 
 
 });

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to *"change the data value to a percentage"*. You can simply change the tick format:

```
.tickFormat(d => Math.round(d*100/d3.max(data)) + "%");
```

Have a look at the following demos. This is a regular bar chart:

```js
var data = [20,45,245,134,267,111,54,333,23];

var w = 500, h = 200, padding = 20;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", w)
 .attr("height", h);
 
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .range([padding, (w - padding)])
 .domain([0, d3.max(data)]);
 
var rects = svg.selectAll(".rects")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("x", xScale(0))
 .attr("y", (d,i) => i*20)
 .attr("height", 14)
 .attr("width", d => xScale(d) - padding)
 .attr("fill", "teal");
 
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
 .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Nothing new here, the ticks show the absolute values, the maximum being 333.

But here is the **same** code, without changing any data, only changing the `tickFormat`:

```js
var data = [20,45,245,134,267,111,54,333,23];

var w = 500, h = 200, padding = 20;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", w)
 .attr("height", h);
 
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
 .range([padding, (w - padding)])
 .domain([0, d3.max(data)]);
 
var rects = svg.selectAll(".rects")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("x", xScale(0))
 .attr("y", (d,i) => i*20)
 .attr("height", 14)
 .attr("width", d => xScale(d) - padding)
 .attr("fill", "teal");
 
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
 .tickFormat(d => Math.round(d*100/d3.max(data)) + "%");

var gX = svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
 .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```